# How to combine multiple case statements in one

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016, case-statement

```
select row_id, pointname,
       CASE when pointname like '%Output%'  
            then (select value)  
       END AS Output,  
       CASE when pointname like '%Over%'     
            then (select value)    
       END AS Over,    
       CASE when pointname like '%Schedule%'  
            then (select value)  
      END AS Schedule  
FROM Table1 JOIN
     TABLE2
     ON "Join Condition"    
WHERE (pointname LIKE '%Output%' AND 'Output' IS NOT NULL) OR  
      (pointname LIKE '%Over%' AND 'Over' IS NOT NULL) OR  
      (pointname LIKE '%Schedule%' AND 'Schedule' IS NOT NULL)
```

======================================================================
Using Case statement I need to display a few columns including column aliases based on certain conditions. Is there a better way of achieving this?
Another question is - can I combine the IS NOT NULL function for the different column values I wish to check?

My first post here, please do let me know if I need to clarify anything.
Thanks!

Expected output-

```
Row_id    pointname     Output    Over   Schedule  
123456    Over           NULL     10       NULL  
123457    Output         4.3222   NULL     NULL   
123458    Schedule       NULL     NULL     6.3333
```

Only, I have 23 such columns, hence the search for optimizing the case statement in my query

Comment: Sample data and expected results could be helpful.

Comment: `AND 'Output' IS NOT NULL`? The string 'Output` is of course not null.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I think here, 'Output' doesn't refer to the string, but to the 'numeric_value' stored in the column alias 'Output'. And so we are checking to see if that bigint/float value IS NOT NULL

Comment: No. Be careful. Single quotes are for string literals. `'Output'` is a string. `Output` would be a column name, as would be `"Output"` in standard SQL and `[Output]` in SQL Server.

Comment: But as far as I can see there is no column named `Output`. (And you cannot use an alias name defined in the `SELECT` clause in the `WHERE` clause.) So you probably want `AND value IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: As to your original question: For 23 columns in your results you need 23 CASE expressions. This is how key/value tables work. They give you the freedom to add new attributes (pointnames in your case) at any time, but they come at a cost (clumsy queries, harder to have type consistency, harder to implement optional and obligatory attributes, ...).

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Thank you for your valuable comments on the 23 case expressions. I'll check the quotes and string value in my code and get back to you. Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want so many columns in the result, you have to use 1 CASE statement for each column. 
The WHERE part could be simplified to:

```
WHERE pointname LIKE '%Output%' OR  
      pointname LIKE '%Over%' OR  
      pointname LIKE '%Schedule%'
```

This condition guarantees that **at least 1** will be `NOT NULL` so no need to check `IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: I need the like in the WHEN statements because of the way the underlying data is. If I don't use IS NOT NULL with the OR condition, then there are many rows with all NULL values (no data for those columns for that specific row_id). I don't want rows with all NULL values